# run jQuery when Ember template changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

My index.html has a `posts` template and a `post` template. The posts template is a series of links that will change what post is being displayed in the `post` template. Some of my posts have content that needs to be adjusted with some jQuery. How can I run the jQuery code every time the post being displayed in the `post` template changes to a different one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a post route, `setupController` is run each time you provide a new model to its route.

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);

    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', function(){
      alert('post has changed, and it\'s been rendered change away');
    });
  }
});
```

Since this generally makes me feel a little guilty (Adding view logic in the route), you can observe the model on the controller (from the view or controller, and each time the model changes fire similar logic.  You might need to throttle it going this route, I'm pretty sure it will fire twice, blanking it, and setting it to a different item.

```
App.PostView = Ember.View.extend({
  watchModel: function(){
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', function(){
      alert('color has changed, and it\'s been rendered change away');
    });

  }.observes('controller.model')
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this issue for awhile. I got the first fix to work. I'm going to try and get the second to work, but I'm not sure I understand it yet. I never created a view for the post template.

Comment: Does ember know to associate `App.PostView` with the post template? Or do I need to switch out the template with `{{#view PostView}}`?

Comment: how is post in the page now?  is it part of the router?  If so Ember will automatically use App.PostRoute, App.PostController, & App.PostView

Comment: I have `<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post">` in the index.html, `App.PostController` & `App.PostRoute` in the app.js, but I did not make a view.

Comment: Observing the model from the view does fire it twice. I'm not sure if this is reliable, but I was able to filter it down to 1 time by checking if the state of the view is `preRender` and only running my jquery then